# Cursor select * with Fetch Next statement

Tags: select, cursor, fetch, teradata

I am working on FETCH STATEMENT inside CURSOR. I need to convert a SQL server script into Teradata.

Following scnerio is working in Teradata( SELECT columns )

SQL SERVER input:---------------------------------------

```
DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR  
    FOR SELECT cnic FROM departments;
OPEN vend_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor;
```

Teradata Output: ---------------------------------

```
replace procedure #anonymous# ()
BEGIN

   declare var#0 VARCHAR(100);
   DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT
         cnic
   FROM departments;
   OPEN vend_cursor;
   FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor INTO
      var#0;
END;
```

But I need to convert the following script(in which select columns is replaced with Select *)
SQL SERVER input:---------------------------------------

```
DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR  
    FOR SELECT * FROM departments;
OPEN vend_cursor  
FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor;
```

Teradata Output: ---------------------------------

```
replace procedure #anonymous# ()
BEGIN

   declare var#0 VARCHAR(100);
   DECLARE vend_cursor CURSOR FOR
   SELECT
         cnic
   FROM departments;
   OPEN vend_cursor;
   FETCH NEXT FROM vend_cursor INTO
      var#0;
END;
```

The output needs to be modified. Now I need to run select * statement, so fetch next needs to be modified. One possible solution in mind is to create a new type of varray and us it in fetch statement after INTO. But that is not working. Can any one please help for possible conversion?